# How can I change the settings of a proj file in VS? (VS-AddIn)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-addins

What I need to do is to write a VS-2010 plugin/addin that modifies a project setting based on some properties.

I know that there's an SDK from Microsoft but I was not able to figure out how to solve the task with it. Please don't misunderstand me, I'm just looking for some hints what to search for, not a complete solution.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The projects are stored in XML I believe. You should be able to read in the file using soapFormatter directly into the equivalent class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project(v=vs.80).aspx